# PHP exec() crashes with no errors

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, error-log

**Hi,**

I believe I really need a PHP expert to solve this issue. We have an application which is crawling the web. The PHP scripts are using proc_open, and exec() and running over a circular reference.

Both scripts that compose the main structure are saving all and every single error on a custom error log, defined this way:

```
//error_log
@ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
@ini_set('log_errors','On');
@ini_set('display_errors','On');
@ini_set('error_log','/var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/resonance/such_a_mess');
```

The problem is simple, after running for some hours or days, the application stops crawling. And there's no error information at all. I've been trying to get more details using Newrelic and XHProf, without any luck.

There's no HTTP server involved on the execution of the scripts as they are being executed like I mentioned:

```
exec("sh -c \"$cmd | logger\" > /dev/null &");
```

Around 3 months on the same situation... really, **the only thing I want at this point is to see a fatal error on the logs**, before going for a solution.

Thanks everyone!
Chris;

Answer (score 0):

you are sending to "black hole" your log

try sent it to a plan file:

```
exec("sh -c \"$cmd | logger\" > /home/your-user/mylog.txt");
```

make sure that you had correct permissions to write.

hugs

Comment: I understand that, but besides that, if there would be any problem on the PHP, it shouldn't be recorded on the error_logs previously stated?